# Create parallel live stream in aws speech to text using package @aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming with node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, speech-to-text, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am working with **@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming** package with **Node js**. My code is working fine for single stream. When I create multiple clients of TranscribeStreamingClient for handling different streams at the same time then only first client is working and other clients are on hold until the first client's connection has been closed. So how can I get parallel response and end stream using above package. My code is written below

```
const {TranscribeStreamingClient,StartStreamTranscriptionCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming");

let client = new TranscribeStreamingClient({
                credentials: config.get("amazon.credentials"),
                region: config.get("amazon.region"),
            });

let streamResponse = await client.send(
                new StartStreamTranscriptionCommand({
                    LanguageCode: this.audioConfig.languageCode,
                    MediaSampleRateHertz: this.audioConfig.sampleRateHertz,
                    MediaEncoding: this.audioConfig.encoding,
                    AudioStream: audioStream(),
                }),
            );

client.destroy();
```

I want **parallel stream response** and **end stream** as well

I have also follow and look below link but not found any thing for parallel stream.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-transcribe-streaming/index.html#send-the-speech-stream

Answer (score 0):

This problem is created because I was using old version of **@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming**. After update the version and using latest version of this package. Now it is working fine for me and fulfil my requirements.